# Force login through mysql

Tags: 7, users, ssl

I have a local install of a Drupal 7 site that will only display admin pages over https such as login and admin type pages. I was unable to disable them before downloading the database. In settings.php I have set secure pages to 0. However when i attempt to login the page simply refreshes and the form is displayed again and i am unable to visit any admin pages. Is there a way to login using mysql instead of having to go through Drupal?

EDIT:

finally got drush running correctly and used 
    drush cc all
after attempting to sign in i got the error message:
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent in _drupal_bootstrap_page_cache()
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent in drupal_send_headers()

the latter is repeated 7 times, the page simply refreshed again.

I ended up creating a temporary sign-in using drush command:
    drush user-login

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to do the following:

1. Set the `securepages_enable` to 0 in settings.php
2. Open a MySQL Client, like HeidiSQL or SQL Pro
3. Truncate the `cache_` tables
4. Reload local site in browser

This should rebuild the variables and then your runtime value will be respected.

Also, check the `.htaccess` file to see that you are not being redirected to HTTPS.

Comment: i ran drupal_clear_all_caches() from html.tpl.php and was still unable to login. the page simply refreshes. I did notice that the site stayed at localhost rather than switching to https localhost/. I commented out the following lines from .htaccess also #RewriteRule ^ - [E=protossl]
  #RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
  #RewriteRule ^ - [E=protossl:s]

Comment: Wait, what? You should be using drush or a mysql client.

Comment: i'll try that also it just takes a while to clear them one by one, also installing drush now

Comment: In a MySQL client you can just highlight the tables, right click, truncate - or equivalent command.